# IIS 7.5 App Pool Custom Account - SSPI Error

Tags: wcf-security, wcf-client

I have changed the user of the app pool my WCF service from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to a custom user.

However, when I now make the call from the client to the service I am getting an SSPI failed error.

Here is the config for the client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>     
      <client>            
            <endpoint 
                name="NetTcpBinding_IStaticService"
                address="net.tcp://app02.company.com/StaticService/StaticService.svc"
                binding="netTcpBinding"                 
                contract="StaticServiceClient.IStaticService">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have been battling with this all day so some help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late now to help you, but I've been getting that SSPI error ('cannot generate SSPI context') and discovered it was linked to having changed the password of the account used as the pool identity.
If you go into IIS and re-set the pool identity account with the new password that fixes it.